# Split string with alternative comma (,)

Tags: java, string, split, tokenize

I know how to tokenize the String, but the Problem is I want to tokenize the as shown below.

```
String st = "'test1, test2','test3, test4'";
```

What I've tried is as below:

```
st.split(",");
```

This is giving me output as:

```
'test1
test2'
'test3
test4'
```

But I want output as:

```
'test1, test2'
'test3, test4'
```

How do i do this?

Comment: You can split on `','`

Comment: perhaps `split("','")` ?

Comment: Are single quotes mandatory?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: No, it's not mandatory

Comment: Do you need syntax that allows single quotes inside the strings, or it's OK to assume that single quotes are always used as delimiters?

Comment: I would be safe and just use a regex. Trying to split, especially with this format, could lead to some issues. If you use a matcher this can easily be avoided and could work on multiple levels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since single quotes are [not mandatory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16402938/split-string-with-alternative-comma/16403153#comment23514665_16402938), `split` will not work, because Java's regex engine does not allow variable-length lookbehind expressions. Here is a simple solution that uses regex to match the content, not the delimiters:

```
String st = "'test1, test2','test3, test4',test5,'test6, test7',test8";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("('[^']*'|[^,]*)(?:,?)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(st);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/NY7NPw).

You can add syntax for escaping single quotes by altering the "content" portion of the quoted substring (currently, it's `[^']*`, meaning "anything except a single quote repeated zero or more times).

Comment: Yep! this does address those 2 issues in my answer!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and reliable solution would be to use a CSV parser. Maybe [Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) would help.

It will scape the strings based on CSV rules. So even `''` could be used within the value without breaking it.

A sample code would be like:
        ByteArrayInputStream baos = new ByteArrayInputStream("'test1, test2','test3, test4'".getBytes());

```
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(baos), ',', '\'');

    String[] read = reader.readNext();
    System.out.println("0: " + read[0]);
    System.out.println("1: " + read[1]);

    reader.close();
```

This would print:

```
0: test1, test2
1: test3, test4
```

If you use maven you can just import the dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And start using it.